# Powershell Running URls from .txt

Tags: powershell, url

I am trying to make a PowerShell script to take urls from a text file and open them in Internet Explorer, or just the default browser on the computer.

I have Outlook client, that has a macro on it that will download all emails with a URL in it to a text file, these URLs are links to download files. The PowerShell Script will go into that text file and open all the URLS in the default browser, then the shell will proceed to automatically download the files.

The PowerShell will be launched from Powershell and be set on a task

How would I start this?

I am not sure how to.

EDIT

file containing the URls

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.youtube.com
```

Example code

```
None, I do not know where to start
```

Comment: Example text file and example code would be useful, we're not mind readers or practice the dark arts of thaumaturgy.

Comment: @Kev I have eddied the post

Comment: All you've provided is links to google and youtube.

Comment: Ok...tell us what the purpose of this exercise is, why are you doing this?

Comment: I am saving emails from outlook that have tinyurls in them to a text file, and then the PowerShell script will go into the text file and open all the urls in the text file

Comment: You need to explain in exact detail in your question exactly what is supposed to happen. You mention a "macro" and VBScript, and then  PowerShell which isn't a macro language or anything to do with VBScript. Please revise with the exact process and steps you wish to achieve and which technologies you wish to use. Your question is far too confusing for anyone to parse or understand.

Comment: I have Outlook client, that has a macro on it that will download all emails with a URL in it to a text file, these URLs are links to download files. The PowerShell Script will go into that text file and open all the URLS in the default browser, then the shell will proceed to automatically download the files.

Comment: Please put this information in the question, not the comments. Explain how the PowerShell script should be launched as well.

Comment: @Kev added to the question

Comment: Start with a PowerShell tutorial. SO is not a replacement for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file named 'urls.txt' this PowerShell script will open each one in a new tab.  I am using Chrome in this example.

The 'urls.txt' file should have the format below...notice each url is on a separate line...

```
yahoo.com
bing.com
google.com
www.cnn.com
```

This is the actual PowerShell script you type into the PowerShell window.  Keep in mind you will need to navigate to the directory where your 'urls.txt' file exists.  You can do that by using the 'cd' (change directory) command.  for example, if your file exists on the Desktop and your profile is under 'admin1' you could write: cd C:\Users\admin1\Desktop

```
$urls = Get-Content urls.txt  
Start-Process -FilePath "chrome.exe" -ArgumentList $urls
```

I realize this question was asked sometime ago but I was also wondering how to do the same.  This should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read the URI's from the text file with `Get-Content` and open them in you default browser with `Start-Process`:

```
Get-Content C:\path\to\links.txt | ForEach-Object { Start-Process $_ }
```